# Format text to date/time format c#

Tags: c#, time, timer

I created a windows 8 app that will have a countdown timer. I have the code for the timer and it works fine, but instead of counting down from 120 seconds I want it to be displayed as 2:00 minutes and countdown from there. But because I use a timer I am not sure how to use the date/time property (if I can even do that). Please help me figure this out.

Here is my timer code:

```
 DispatcherTimer timer;
 private int counter = 120;

 public ArcadeMode()
 {
     InitializeComponent();
     timer = new DispatcherTimer();
     timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
     timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
     timer.Start();
  }

  async void timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
  {
     await Time.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Low, () => { Time.Text = counter.ToString(); });
     counter--;
   }
```

Comment: You can simply use modulus operator `%`. For minutes `(value / 60) % 60` and for hours `value / 360`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe there are faster/terser ways, but this should at least display the timer the way you'd like (untested):

```
Time.Text = string.Format("{0}:{1}", (counter / 60), (counter % 60).ToString().PadLeft(2,'0'));
```

Comment: @UserDev6765 if its working properly, give him upvote, he deserves it.

Answer (score 6):

```
Time.Text = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(counter).ToString();
```

this will give you output like `00:01:00` if input is `60`

Answer (score 2):

convert it to Datetime instance, and .ToString("the format you want")